# first m3u8 ts segment not working after mp4 to m3u8 conversion by node js

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

**index.js**

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const process = require('process');


const args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (args.length !== 4) {
    console.error('Incorrect number of arguments');
    process.exit(1);
  }
const startTime = args[0];
const timeDuration = args[1];
const inputFile = args[2];
const outputFile=args[3];

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

ffmpeg(inputFile)
  .setStartTime(startTime)
  .setDuration(timeDuration)
  .output(outputFile)
  .outputOptions('-hls_list_size 0')
  .on('end', function(err) {
    if(!err) { console.log('conversion Done') }
  })
  .on('error', function(err){
    console.log('error: ', err)
  }).run();
```

> Here is the index.js and I'm running it by hitting the command on the terminal
>
> `node index.js 5 40 ./input.mp4 ./output.m3u8`
>
> Here 5 is for starting time and 40 is the time duration in seconds. The process creates m3u8 with ts files but the first ts file isn't getting created properly. It's been created in kb format while all the other files in mb format.
> [image]

> the output_test0 isn't getting generated properly and so that's why while playing the m3u8 file, the first few seconds is just static picture. This issue has been happening with the first ts output only. Any trick on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a problem with the video player? Try to rule out node.js by executing the ffmpeg command directly in a terminal and see if the result is different.

Comment: I tried this in command line ``` ffmpeg -i f1.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8``` and it works perfectly fine. I tried to set output options in node js too but the first ts file still isn't working

Comment: Use [the start event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg#start-ffmpeg-process-started) to print the command line and configure your node.js code to obtain a command line equivalent to the one that you already know that works.

Comment: I found the issue.  Here is the right command line 
 " ffmpeg -i test.m3u8 -ss 6.2 -y -t 45 -profile:v baseline  -level 3 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls output_test.m3u8 "
 . But node js is passing this in command line 
" ffmpeg -ss 6.2 -i test.m3u8  -y -t 45 -profile:v baseline  -level 3 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls output_test.m3u8" 
basically -ss [start_time] should go after -i [input] . Any trick how to fix that? The command needs to be output seeking. Here is the document link 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment about how it seems to be caused by the use of input seeking instead of output seeking:

Use `seek()` or `seekOutput()` instead of `setStartTime()`. [The documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg#seektime-seek-output) describes the difference:

> #### seek(time): seek output
>
> ---
>
> **Aliases:** `seekOutput()`.
>
> Seeks streams before encoding them into the output. This is different from calling seekInput() in that the offset will only apply to one output. This is also slower, as skipped frames will still be decoded (but dropped).
>
> The time argument may be a number (in seconds) or a timestamp string (with format [[hh:]mm:]ss[.xxx]).
>
> ```js
> ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi')
>   .seekInput('1:00')
>
>   .output('from-1m30s.avi')
>   .seek(30)
>
>   .output('from-1m40s.avi')
>   .seek('0:40');
> ```

`setStartTime()` is an alias for `seekInput()`. From [the same documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg#seekinputtime-set-input-start-time):

> #### seekInput(time): set input start time
>
> ---
>
> **Alias:** `setStartTime()`.
>
> Seeks an input and only start decoding at given time offset.

Note that `seek()` or `seekOutput()` should be applied to the output and not on the input as `seekInput()`, i.e. after `output()`.

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to solve it.  Here is the link to my updated code https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-brahmagupta-8dins
Basically what I did was, removed setStartTime() and replaced it with outputOption('-ss',startTime) , for this the command became -i [file path] -ss [start_time]. Now it is in output seeking format so it worked. Thanks :)